black screen after login into kali inside virtualbox [maybe display bad settings]
I after install Kali inside oracle VirtualBox I can`t login to it and see this black screen:

And when i want to close it VirtualBox shows me this:

I think it is incorrect display settings. These are my display settings for Kali inside VMware:

I should how set the video memory and other settings for work properly?

It may be helpful to crop the images to focus on what you are trying to show us. Also, messages and warnings should be written out in your post, as this is going to be easier to read and will also help search engines find your content.

Kali is a complex tool designed to be used by competent technologists. It is not a good first-time Linux system. Please read this thread thoroughly: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361

I need Kali and its tools and have used it before. Also don`t see any warning or error.

Logs should have been generated for the VM, what errors contained in those logs exist, and have you tried to troubleshoot any of them?

Oh, I found a log in machine dir. I uploaded it at https://github.com/linux7563/log_error/blob/main/VBox.log.3
